# Using Timestamp in java sql prepared statement

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, prepared-statement, sql-timestamp

I am trying to execute a select query using prepared statement in Java.
In Where clause im checking for a condition on Timestamp type column as shown below.

```
String selectSQL = "select * from db.keycontacts WHERE CREATEDDATETIME>?";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement(selectSQL);
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(1, convertStrToTimestamp(lastSyncTimeStamp));
resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery(selectSQL );
```

//function to convert timestampString to java.sql.Timestamp

```
private java.sql.Timestamp convertStrToTimestamp(String dateTimeStr){

      java.sql.Timestamp timeStampDate = null;
      try {
            DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");//2015-05-11 18:26:55
            java.util.Date dateObj = (java.util.Date)formatter.parse(dateTimeStr);
            timeStampDate = new Timestamp(dateObj.getTime());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

      return timeStampDate;
  }
```

When the query is executed, getting following exception.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1
```

So where exactly im going wrong here?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the parameter from

```
resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery(selectSQL );
```

and change to

```
resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery( );
```

The query you passed in `preparedStatement.executeQuery(selectSQL );` takes priority over the query you passed in `connect.prepareStatement(selectSQL);` which is the simple string (`"select * from db.keycontacts WHERE CREATEDDATETIME>?"`) in which you dint set any parameter so there is a syntax error for `?`

and you can also say that statement is prepared at `PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement(selectSQL);` since `executeQuery()` is inherited from [Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery(java.lang.String)) it will execute query without preparing it.

Comment: Thanks Akash for the solution and explaination.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","rootpasswd");
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select p.PARKING_NUMBER, p.TYPE, p.AVAILABLE, "
            + "t.PARKING_NUMBER, t.VEHICLE_REG_NUMBER, t.PRICE, t.IN_TIME, t.OUT_TIME "
            + "from parking p inner join ticket t on p.PARKING_NUMBER = t.PARKING_NUMBER "
            + "where t.In_TIME = ?");
    Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(BigDecimal.valueOf(expectedInTime.getTime()/1000d).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).longValue()*1000);
    //To Round Half Up from millisecond (d for double) to second (long so no d) because MySQL do this.
    ps.setTimestamp(1, ts);
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).